# HTML POST data is not getting to the processing script on the first send

Tags: html, perl, post, cgi-bin

I have a perl web application that displays a select list with options.

When user makes a selection and clicks submit, it shoots the post data to the same script to process it and display the data.

Problem is that on the first try the select field's value doesn't always go through. But when I reload the page it resends the form data and I get the results.

Here is how the post data is obtained:

```
my $query = new CGI;
my $cgi_sessionid  = $query->param("sessionid");
my $cgi_reporttype = $query->param("reporttype");
my $cgi_to_page    = $query->param("to_page");
my $cgi_propertyid = $query->param("propertyid");
my $cgi_rptformat  = $query->param("rptformat");
```

EDIT:

Form looks like:

```
<form action="/report/propreport.pl" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="reporttype" value="propdetail" />
    <input type="hidden" name="to_page" value="Overview" />
    <td width="20%">Property</td>
    <td>
    <select name="propertyid">
        <option value="1">name1</option>
        <option value="2">name1</option>
        <option value="3">name1</option>
        ....
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Property Details">
</form>
```

In chrome inspector it sometimes closes the form right after the opening form tag.

It looks like:

```
<form action="/report/propreport.pl" method="post"></form>
    <input type="hidden" name="reporttype" value="propdetail" />
    <input type="hidden" name="to_page" value="Overview" />
    <td width="20%">Property</td>
    <td>
    <select name="propertyid">
        <option value="1">name1</option>
        <option value="2">name1</option>
        <option value="3">name1</option>
        ....
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Property Details">
</form>
```

The form is generated through a variable:

```
my $propQueryTemplate = <<ENDTXT;
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Reporting Interface</title>
<style type="text/css">
$cssCode
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
//Some JS
-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="mainhead">
<td colspan="2">
As-Built Reporting Interface
</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>

<tr class="contenthead">
<td colspan="2">Property Details</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:black">
<td colspan="2"><img src="/otrs-web/spacer.gif" height="1" width="1" /></td></tr>
</tr>
<tr class="contentbody">
<form action="/report/propreport.pl" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="reporttype" value="propdetail" />
<input type="hidden" name="to_page" value="Overview" />
<td width="20%">Property</td>
<td>
$propDropDown
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Property Details">
</form>
ENDTXT
```

I am a little at loss here.

EDIT.

IT feels that the data from the client doesn't always get to the server, when I open another tab and select a different option from the list the first one is being displayed as if the first selection is being stuck sometimes. The behavior is inconsistent.

EDIT.

It seems that the issue lies with the form being displayed incorrectly with the closing tag being moved to the end of the form. I am not sure what is causing this since the form is just printed out to the document.

Comment: What does your HTML form look like?

Comment: can we see the whole script with HTML?

Comment: In the edit. Script is 6k lines long unfortunately, I'm restoring some legacy code on a new env.

Comment: If you see form closing sometimes after first line it seems problem in form generating code. How is the form generated?

Comment: @w.k it's a variable defined as my $propQueryTemplate = <<ENDTXT; .... <form body>